# Oracle: Group data by decade

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a customer table with below details :

DOB is a date datatype in Oracle

```
Customer ID   Name            DOB
1             Babu          20-07-1987
2             MohanLal      20-04-1962
3             Mammootty     20-04-1961
```

Desired result:

```
Decade start    Decade end     No_of_customers
1960-01-01       1969-12-31            2
1980-01-01       1989-12-31            1
```

Comment: I think you need Decade end to be '1969-12-31' instead of '1969-01-01'

Comment: yes that's correct. I have update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below SQL query:

```
 SELECT 
    substr(TO_CHAR(DOB,'YYYY-MM-DD'),1,3)||'0-01-01' as DECADE_START,
    substr(TO_CHAR(DOB,'YYYY-MM-DD'),1,3)||'9-12-31' as DECADE_END,
    count(1) AS NO_OF_CUSTOMERS
    FROM 
    customer_table
    group by 
    substr(TO_CHAR(DOB,'YYYY-MM-DD'),1,3)
```

Comment: For short, I think you only need `SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(DOB, 'YYYY'), 1, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

Use trunc function with proper date formatting :

```
select 10*trunc(to_char(DOB,'yyyy')/10) "Decade", count(1) "No_of_customers"
  from tab
 group by 10*trunc(to_char(DOB,'yyyy')/10)
 order by 1;
```

I lately realized your last edit. With respect to that, you may use the following :

```
with t as
(
 select trunc(to_date(10*trunc(to_char(DOB,'yyyy')/10),'yyyy'),'year')   Decade_Start,
        trunc(to_date(10*ceil(to_char(DOB,'yyyy')/10),'yyyy'),'year')-1  Decade_End
   from tab
 )
 select t.*, count(1) No_of_customers 
   from t  
 group by Decade_Start, Decade_End
 order by 1;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ecbca/3)